# Return distinct values from multiple columns in one query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

i have searched but i did not find any good answer actually i got the distinct value but the problem is i am applying query on two columns it should return distinct values but it is returning these values

```
Au |FAA303
Au |FAA505
```

From my table i want to appear **`Au`** only one time as it is now associated with the **`FAA303`** and **`FAA505`**

What i want is like this

```
Au |FAA303
   |FAA505
```

This is my query in postgresql. I am kinda new to the database queries.

```
select distinct column1, column2
from table_name
```

Comment: Please do it in your application code. SQL is not the suitable tool to do this

Comment: @GurV i did not get you sorry! ?

Comment: You should do this job using a reporting tool not using a sql sentence.

Comment: so there is not a possible way to do this in query? @McNets

Comment: not using a single sentence like `select col1, col2 from... but hide duplicates on col1`

Comment: but there must be a way because these should not be associated with each other

Comment: If they should not be associated with eachother, why do they appear in the same record in your table in the first place??

Comment: yeah in the table they are associated might be i am not going on a correct way. Correct me if i am wrong. but it should distinct after the query?

Comment: The distinct applies to the combination of all selected fields together, not to the first field only. What you want is something you would do in an application that performs this query, not in the query itself.

Comment: ok thankx! i should do more search on it. Thankx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `distinct` keyword applies to the combination of all selected fields, not to the first one only.

Suppressing repeated values is something you would typically do in an application that connects to your database and performs the query.

Just to show you that it is possible in SQL, I provide you this query, but please consider doing this in the application instead:

```
select  case row_number() over (partition by column1 order by column2)
            when 1 then column1
        end as column1,
        column2
from (
    select   distinct column1,
             column2
    from     table_name
    order by column1, column2
)
```

Comment: yes i m doing in application like codeigniter but also want to test first on the database. Thats why and i m using postgresql